# Adding value to search result from jSON resp

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Currently I am having the list of titles generating with below logic, Now I want to add data to the title list + code of that title from `response` data

```
const title = responseData.map(item => {
                return { label: item.title, value: item._id };
            });
```

This is the response I'm having in `item` Now I want like after the fox (OF), So the goal is adding (OF) after title, currently I am able to get title, but want to add the `code` along with the result.
[image]

See the prototype of `item`

[image]

Like here, I want the number of times it has in registration array, I want to show it in a single row. Currently its like below, But I want it like if there's 2 result then I want it 2 time in a single row.
[image]

Comment: Confusing. What you are trying to acheive???

Comment: Yes i am too please add what you get and what you want

Comment: I want the `title + OF` in the final result for example like this `After the fox (OF)`

@Alex

Comment: @Nandani Then you ca do with `item.title  +"(" + item.code + ")"`

Comment: @Subburaj Please see the prototype, `item.title` won't work, there's an array object for `registration`

Comment: @Subburaj please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get code like this :

```
const title = responseData.map(item => {
                return { label:`${item.title} ${item.regisration[0].registration_type.code}`, 
                         value: item._id };
            });
```

this is only for first element in registration!

here registration is array if you want to get each registration use map method too, this example like your code:

```
 let options= [{
  id:1,
  registration:[
    {
      registration_type:{
        id:1,
        code:"fo"
      }
    },
    {
       registration_type:{
        id:2,
        code:"fox"
      }
    }
  ],
  title:"hello world"
}
              ]

options.map(data=>{
  data.registration.map(reg=>{
    console.log(`${data.title} ${reg.registration_type.code}`)
  })
})
```

Comment: not working, its under registration, please check the picture with the question

Comment: Its working but like if I am getting 2 results in (refer: prototype) then I want that result should show two times the same results. Can you help me with that too?

Comment: Please help @Adel

Comment: @Nandani try to call a function inside the label key and make sure label get that item loop through with every result you have

Comment: @narayanmaity can you explain it? or code it? bcz i didn't get it

Comment: can it be done taking an empty array and pushing it in and then joining it back? Like check the prototype in question, if there's 2 registrations then i want to print both side by side. example: title (ex), title (ui) Separated with comma.

Comment: @Nandani registration is an array use `map` to get each value you want like what  i did above !

Comment: Should I take empty array?

Comment: Like I want multiple results, in the same raw if there's multiple `registration`

Comment: so you want to count  the code in each registration??

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want output something like this

```
{
  _id:asadadd,
  code:"OF",
  title:"abc"  
}
```

you can code `Object.assign({data:{title:"abc"}})`

Comment: please check the prototype in the question

Answer (score 0):

Check this I'm not sure maybe this code will help you

```
    const title = responseData.map(item => {
  return { label: loopingResult(item), value: item._id };
});

function loopingResult(item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < item.registration.length; i++) {
    const result = `${item.title} ${item.registration[i].registration_type.code}`;
    return result.split(',');
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any changes in output or the same (as the accepted result ) ??

Comment: After the fox (OF) After the fox (OF) is this what you want as output

Comment: can it be done taking an empty array and pushing it in and then joining it back? Like check the prototype in question, if there's 2 registrations then i want to print both side by side. example: title (ex), title (ui) Separated with comma

Comment: Look the result I made some changes

Comment: No luck, getting single entry only