# show result List as per count

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[image]

Like here, I want the number of times it has in registration array, I want to show it in a single row. Currently its like below, But I want it like if there's 2 result then I want it 2 time in a single row.

[image]

So here if you check the prototype(of `item`), You can see 2 count, so i want to show 2 results, along sides.

```
const title = responseData.map(item => {

                    return { label: `${item.title} (${item.registration[0].registration_type.code}) (${item.registration.length.toString()})`, value: item._id };

            });
```

Comment: I think for each requirement you are posting different questions, your previous questions is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972491/adding-value-to-search-result-from-json-resp?noredirect=1#comment104201110_58972491.

Comment: @Subburaj can you help me with this?

Comment: This is different one kindly read the question @Subburaj

Comment: Still I am  not clear what is your problem. Make the question clear with sample data (remove the image and post plain JSON object of your data) and mention what you exactly want

Comment: It is solved, with the upvoted answer @Subburaj

Comment: Accept the answer, if it really solved the problem . Upvote doesn't mean its accepted

Comment: The above code should work. What's the error in that??

Comment: @Subburaj  I want Like here, I want the number of times it has in registration array, I want to show it in a single row. Currently its like below, But I want it like if there's 2 result then I want it 2 time in a single row.

Comment: Whats below here??

Comment: @Subburaj  can it be done taking an empty array and pushing it in and then joining it back?

Like check the prototype in question, if there's 2 registrations then i want to print both side by side. example: title (ex), title (ui) 

Separated with comma

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the data you want in each row is all stored inside each element in the item.registration array.

```
const title = responseData.map(item => {
    // map all the values inside the registration on to an array of labels
    const labels = item.registration.map(registration => {
        return `${item.title} (${registration.registration_type.code})`; 
    })

    // Join the labels created above with a comma separating them
    return { label: labels.join(', '), value: item._id };
});
```